# Creating a database with selenium webdriver and exporting to CSV?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I've written a program that uses Selenium webdriver to open up Chrome and scrape Craigslist for a specific query (in my case, it's a Mazda Miata).

I have it so it prints out the title of the post, date of the post, price of the item, and spits out the item URL.

Here is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#import schedule

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request 


cars = []  
class CraigslistScaper(object): 
    def __init__(self,query,location,max_price,transmission): 
        self.query = query
#        self.sort=sort
        self.location = location
#        self.postal = postal
        self.max_price = max_price
        self.transmission = auto_transmission


#https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/cta?query=mazda+miata&sort=rel&max_price=6000&auto_transmission=1
        self.url = "https://{}.craigslist.org/search/cta?query={}&sort=rel&max_price={}&auto_transmission={}".format(self.location, self.query, self.max_price, self.transmission)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/MohitAsthana/Desktop/chromedriver')
        self.delay = 5

    def load_craigslist_url(self): 
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay)
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"searchform")))              
            print("page is ready")
        except TimeoutError: 
            print('Loading took too much time')

    def extract_post_information(self): 
        all_posts = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result-row')
        titles = []
        dates = []
        prices = []


        for post in all_posts: 
            title = post.text.split('$')

            if title[0] == '':
                title = title[1]
            else:
                title = title[0]

            title = title.split("\n")
            price = title[0]
            title = title[-1]

            title = title.split(' ')
            month = title[0]
            day = title[1]
            date = month + " " + day
            title = ' '.join(title[2:])




              print('PRICE: ' + (price))
              print('TITLE: ' + (title))
              print('DATE: ' + date)




    def extract_post_urls(self): 
        url_list = []
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source,'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': "result-title hdrlnk"}):
            print(link.get('href'))
            url_list.append(url_list)
        return url_list

    def quit(self): 
        self.driver.close()

location = "sfbay" 
#postal = "94539" 
max_price = "25000"
#radius = "250"
auto_transmission = 1
query = "Mazda Miata"

scraper = CraigslistScaper(query,location,max_price,auto_transmission)        

scraper.load_craigslist_url()
scraper.extract_post_information()
scraper.extract_post_urls()
scraper.quit()
```

I want to save all my results to a CSV file, with column A showing the title, column B is the date, and column C is the price, and column D is the URL of the Craigslist post.

My goal with this script is to eventually automate this so it runs every day and will come up with an updated CSV file with all the Mazda Miata prices. I can then plot the historical data and maybe even use this as a training dataset to predict Mazda Miata prices.

My question is how do I save the title, date, price, and Craigslist URL into a CSV?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @demouser123 edited the question for more clarity. I want to save the price, title, date, and URL into a CSV file so I can use Pandas to visualize the data.